# Adjust height on fixed image when (over-)scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

i am trying to achieve an effect in angularjs/ionic, that
handles an image resize upon scrolling beyond the content ("bounce effect").

I.g. a header-image is under the header-bar, that should adjusts in height, when
the the scroll area is pulled down

[Here is an Example of what i'm looking for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpPdW.gif)

I was trying to achieve this by using the $ionicScrollDelegate method getScrollPosition(), since that gives me scroll position. But the main problem is, that the image is inside the scroll area and that bounce box outside. So i cannot access the height of this image.

Anyone tried something similar?
I was searching on here and everywhere i could think of, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I have zero clue if this helps or not, but I skimmed through your spec\demo, and it seemed similar (but different) to something I did for a project recently. I'm sure there are hundreds of libs for this, but I pruned it out of the project and put it on my github at https://github.com/ardkevin84/fixed-scroller. The module takes a watch element that you'd like to act on. It affects that element in response to scroll events, considering bounds like min\max affected range. I used it to set the top css attr, but you can shuffle the code to change any attr(s)